# Incorrect placement of equations, spanned and centered

Tags: equations

The following set of equations, produce an output which is justified in center (although I haven't set such an option) and also the equations are spanned on two columns (which again I didn't set such option)

```
\begin{alignat}{2}
   &E_{\mathrm{hit-L1}} = E_{L1}(\mathrm{tag+data}) \\
   &E_{\mathrm{miss-L1}} =  E_{L1}(\mathrm{tag}) \\
   &E_{\mathrm{hit-local-L2}} = E_{L2}(\mathrm{tag+data}) \\
   &E_{\mathrm{miss-local-L2}} = E_{L2}(\mathrm{tag}) \\
   &E_{\mathrm{hit-peer-L2}} = E_{\mathrm{dir}}+E_{\mathrm{router}}+E_{L2}(\mathrm{tag+data}) \\
   &E_{\mathrm{miss-peer-L2}} = E_{L2}(\mathrm{tag}) + E_{\mathrm{dir}} \\
   &E = E_{\mathrm{hit-L1}} + (1-h_{1}) \times (E_{\mathrm{miss-L1}}& \\
        h_{2} \times E_{\mathrm{hit-local-L2}} + (1-h_{2}) \times& \\
        \big( E_{\mathrm{miss-local-L2}} + h_{3} \times E_{\mathrm{hit-peer-L2}}& \\
        +(1-h_{3}) \big( E_{\mathrm{miss-peer-L2}} + E_{mem} \big) \big) ) 
\end{alignat}
```

and the output looks like

[image]

I would like to have one columned equations and the numbers should be  in front of them (right side of the equations). Also, since I have used `\\`, the last big equations should be paste in multiple lines and not spanning to two columns.

Comment: What would you like to have, exactly?

Comment: Please see the udpated post

Comment: For future reference, while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Please provide some information about the intended meaning of the `-` symbols in the subscipts: Are they supposed to be minus signs, simple dashes/hyphens, or en-dashes that indicate a range (e.g., "from miss to local to L2"). If it's the second option, you should probably use `\textrm` instead of `\mathrm`. If it's the third option, you may want to write `\textrm{miss--local--L2}` to generate real typographic en-dashes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, you did request the output exactly as shown.  An `&` specifies that the text to the left is right aligned, and the text to the right of the `&` is left aligned. Thus, the first `&` in each line specified that the text following it is to be *left* aligned, which is did for the first 7 lines. Then on the last three lines you added a single `&` at the *end* of the line (and none at the beginning). So the text following the single `&` is set to be left aligned (i.e., the text before the single `&` is to be right aligned) with the leading `&` in the lines above.

I think what you want is:

[image]

### Notes:

- For the lines you don't want numbered you can apply `\nonumber`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{2}
   E_{\mathrm{hit-L1}} &= E_{L1}(\mathrm{tag+data}) \\
   E_{\mathrm{miss-L1}} &=  E_{L1}(\mathrm{tag}) \\
   E_{\mathrm{hit-local-L2}} &= E_{L2}(\mathrm{tag+data}) \\
   E_{\mathrm{miss-local-L2}} &= E_{L2}(\mathrm{tag}) \\
   E_{\mathrm{hit-peer-L2}} &= E_{\mathrm{dir}}+E_{\mathrm{router}}+E_{L2}(\mathrm{tag+data}) \\
   E_{\mathrm{miss-peer-L2}} &= E_{L2}(\mathrm{tag}) + E_{\mathrm{dir}} \\
   E &= E_{\mathrm{hit-L1}} + (1-h_{1}) \times \Big(E_{\mathrm{miss-L1}} \nonumber\\
        &\qquad h_{2} \times E_{\mathrm{hit-local-L2}} + (1-h_{2}) \times \nonumber\\
        &\qquad \big( E_{\mathrm{miss-local-L2}} + h_{3} \times E_{\mathrm{hit-peer-L2}} \nonumber\\
        &\qquad +(1-h_{3}) \big( E_{\mathrm{miss-peer-L2}} + E_{mem} \big) \big) \Big) \nonumber
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rather separate the last equation from the others, not aligning it, but using a `multlined` environment. Semantically, it seems to be different, as it uses the left members of the six first equations. It makes this equation more readable, in my opinion. Still for readability I changed a pair of `\big` to `\Big`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
   E_{\mathrm{hit-L1}} &= E_{L1}(\mathrm{tag+data}) \\
   E_{\mathrm{miss-L1}} &=  E_{L1}(\mathrm{tag}) \\
   E_{\mathrm{hit-local-L2}} &= E_{L2}(\mathrm{tag+data}) \\
   E_{\mathrm{miss-local-L2}} &= E_{L2}(\mathrm{tag}) \\
   E_{\mathrm{hit-peer-L2}} &= E_{\mathrm{dir}}+E_{\mathrm{router}}+E_{L2}(\mathrm{tag+data}) \\
   E_{\mathrm{miss-peer-L2}} &= E_{L2}(\mathrm{tag}) + E_{\mathrm{dir}}
\end{align}\vskip-1\baselineskip
\begin{equation}
E  =\begin{multlined}[t]
E_{\mathrm{hit-L1}} + (1-h_{1}) \times
 \Big(E_{\mathrm{miss-L1}} h_{2} \times E_{\mathrm{hit-local-L2}}+ (1-h_{2}) \times\\[-3pt]
     \Big( E_{\mathrm{miss-local-L2}} + h_{3} \times E_{\mathrm{hit-peer-L2}}
        +(1-h_{3}) \big( E_{\mathrm{miss-peer-L2}} + E_{\mathrm{mem}} \big) \Big) \Big)
   \end{multlined}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the hack to space up `1\baselineskip` is probably not robust if it happens to fall at the end of a page.  however, grouping everything with `gather` and using `alignedat` won't give every line an equation number.  this comment is just to let you know that assigning equation numbers in such a situation is on the list to be considered when `amsmath` is next updated.